# Super Simple Authentication railscast

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following along with the rails cast for Super Simple Authentication 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/21-super-simple-authentication
I'm using rails 3 so I'm changing the routes and the name of the controller from sessions to user that's really all that changes.

I have ran into an issue where in the screencast it has in the new.html.erb files it has the below.

```
<div class="content">
    <p>
        <% form_tag user_path do %>
            Password: <%= text_field_tag :password %>
        <%end%>
    </p>
</div>
```

When I try this I get an error `http://localhost:3000/login`

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user"}

When I looked up my routes using rake I get this.

```
 user_index GET    /user(.:format)               user#index
                  POST   /user(.:format)               user#create
         new_user GET    /user/new(.:format)           user#new
        edit_user GET    /user/:id/edit(.:format)      user#edit
             user GET    /user/:id(.:format)           user#show
                  PUT    /user/:id(.:format)           user#update
                  DELETE /user/:id(.:format)           user#destroy
            login        /login(.:format)              user#new
           logout        /logout(.:format)             user#destroy
```

In my routes file I have this.

```
  resources :user 
  match 'login' => 'user#new'
  match 'logout' => 'user#destroy'
```

So I don't know how the screen-casts file works with the line <% form_tag user_path do %>
if I change that to **new_user_path** then it brings me to the new.html.erb page. But now the 
Password: <%= text_field_tag :password %> filed doesn't show on the page. What am I doing wrong here.

**UPDATE:**

So I created a controller called sessions instead of my user controller which should have no difference, but based on SHUMAcupcake comment I'm doing it wrong, I decided to delete my user controller and create one called sessions just like the screen-cast. As I suspected the same issues happen. The only difference now is all my routes are named sessions instead of user as to be expected.

Yes I have restarted my app and still the same issue. Please see my rake routes output and you can see that user_path is going to the show action instead of where it's meant to go which according to the screen-cast its meant to go to create action.

Comment: do you have methods for create and destroy in your user controller? And you need a sumbit_tag for sending the data in your form

Comment: Yes SHUMAcupcake I have the create and destroy methods just like the screen cast has in my UserController. I can't even get to adding the submit tag as you can see if you read through my post it says I get an error because of the <% form_tag user_path do %> ERROR No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user"}

Comment: According to my routes the line user_path is going to the show action so how in the screencast its going to the new action. when the new action is new_user_path. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Try restarting your Rails app

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to use plural in your path variable, and also write the result of the form_tag method to HTML, like so:

```
<%= form_tag users_path do %>
```

Comment: Good answer, and thank you for posting a code example as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
map.login 'login', :controller => 'users', :action => 'new' 
map.logout 'logout', :controller => 'users', :action => 'destroy'
```

And check if you have a show view in your users mapp and check you you have a show method in you user controller.

Something like this in users_controller.rb:

```
def show
   #some code
end
```

Comment: I already have this in my routes file. see above the only difference is the syntax is different now in rails 3. No need to use map.   match 'login' => 'user#new'
  match 'logout' => 'user#destroy'

Comment: You are doing it wrong, you dont need to put this logic in the user-controller. You should create a sessions controller and application method that check if the user is logged in by checking the session variable and have some if statsments the check if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: What not sure what you mean. I'm copying the screencast exactly. The only difference is the name of my Controller from sessions to user.

Comment: SHUMAcupcake why would naming my controller sessions be any different from user isn't it just a naming convention or does name a controller sessions give it some other functionality that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I am not talking about naming convention dude! You need to create a separate controller to put this kind of logic. You should read how sessions work on webbrowsers and maybe get back to the basic with ruby and rails.

Comment: Thanks dude for the big help, so maybe you can explain what you are talking about instead of calling me dude. I'm just asking for help here.